How to Derive the Binomial Coefficient Upper Bound and Final Inequality in "Scheduling Multithreaded Computations by Work Stealing"?
In the paper Scheduling Multithreaded Computations by Work Stealing under the section "Atomic accesses and the recycling game", it mentions the binomial coefficient approximation:
$$ \binom{m(P-1)}{\Delta} \leq \left( \frac{emP}{\Delta} \right)^{\Delta} $$
How is this upper bound derived? I tried using Stirling's approximation but couldn't achieve the result.
Additionally, in the following inequality:
$$
\Pr \left\{ \delta \geq \Delta \right\} \leq \left( \frac{emP}{\Delta} \right)^{\Delta} P^{-\Delta} \\
= \left( \frac{em}{\Delta} \right)^{\Delta} \\
\leq \frac{\epsilon}{P},
$$
whenever $\Delta\ge \max\{2em,\text{lg }P+\text{lg}(1/\epsilon)\}$.
How is the final inequality $ \leq \frac{\epsilon}{P} $ obtained?

For the first question, start with $\binom{m(P-1)}{\Delta}\le \binom{mP}{\Delta}$, and then use the result in this question to conclude that $\binom{mP}{\Delta}\le \left(\frac{emP}{\Delta}\right)^\Delta$. Alternatively, note that $$\binom{mP}{\Delta}=\frac{(mp)!/(mp-\Delta)!}{\Delta!}\le \frac{(mP)^\Delta}{\Delta!},$$ because $(mp)!/(mp-\Delta)!$ is a product of $\Delta$ numbers which are all at most $mP$. Then, you can use Stirling's approximation on the denominator. Specifically, use the fact that Stirling's approximation of $\Delta!$ is actually a lower bound for $\Delta!$, so $\Delta!\ge \Delta^\Delta e^{-\Delta}\sqrt{2\pi\Delta}\ge  \Delta^\Delta e^{-\Delta}$.
For the second question, the fact that $\Delta \ge 2em$ implies that $\frac{em}{\Delta}\le \frac12$, so
$$
\left(\frac{em}{\Delta}\right)^\Delta\le \left(\frac12\right)^{\Delta}\le \left(\frac12\right)^{\text{lg } P+\text{lg}( 1/\epsilon)}=\frac{\epsilon}{P}.
$$
